# PHP global include path not working as expected

Tags: php, include, include-path

I'm trying to use a file located in `C:/WEBserver/php_includes`. The file in question is called `stripe.inc.php`, however when I `include('stripe.inc.php')` I get this error:

> Failed opening
> 'E:/Webserver/MY_NAME/COMPANY_SITE/www/site/templates/stripe.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\WEBserver\php_includes;e:\Webserver\MY_NAME\global-lib') in E:\Webserver\MY_NAME\COMPANY_SITE\www\site\assets\cache\FileCompiler\site\templates\register-payment.php on line 868

Note that `MY_NAME` and `MY_COMPANY` are actual names, I just removed them for this question. Also note that the current file I'm in is located in a folder called `templates`, and php is looking for `stripe.inc.php` in that folder. It isn't even looking in the folder set as the global include path.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `include('stripe.inc.php')` is looking for a file in the same directory the page is running on, currently `E:/Webserver/MY_NAME/COMPANY_SITE/www/site/templates`. If the file is in another directory, the best bet is to provide the full path to the directory.

Comment: @user3783243 I'm not sure what code to post other than the one line include I'm using: include('stripe.inc.php');

Comment: @aynber We would like to use the global include path as often as possible so if files get moved the include paths would not break.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your include path is not configured well :

```
set_include_path(string $include_path);
include('stripe.inc.php');
```

If this works, then you should revise your php.ini file :

```
php_value include_path ".;C:\WEBserver\php_includes"
```